# How can i get output in my HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm try to create a form with two input (Username and password) and one button(submit).
my index.html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form>
        <p>username</p>
        <input type="text" id="username" />
        <p>Password</p>
        <input  type="text" id="Password" /><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="getinfo()">submit</button>
     </form>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

then adding some javascript code for just getting a username and password which enter in **username** and **password** field in html form.
my main.js code

```
 function getinfo(){
        var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        alert("Name = " + username + "password = " + password);
    }
```

But i don't getting any alert. i'm try to find out but i can't understand why my code is not working.when i search internet i find some related post but unfortunately it did not help,it's maybe for my little understanding in javascript , but i need help about this.

Comment: Check your console for errors

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `id` in `<input type="text" id="Password" />` has an upper case *P*, while in javascript you are calling it with a lower case *p*.

---

**Note:**

Problems in your javascript code are usually easy to find using the browser console to check for errors. The error thrown here was:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

so it was immediately obvious that one of the elements doesn't exist on the page.

---

**Here is the corrected code:**

```js
function getinfo() {
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
   alert("Name = " + username + " password = " + password);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form>
        <p>username</p>
        <input type="text" id="username" value="" />
        <p>Password</p>
        <input type="text" id="password" value="" /><br>
        <button type="button" onclick="getinfo()">submit</button>
     </form>
     <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Good answer.  I would also recommend taking the opportunity to _teach_.  OP might benefit from some tips on using the browser console and other troubleshooting techniques.

Comment: @cale_b You are right, I will edit to include that too. Thanks

Comment: when i'm getting my answer then i'm going to mark it as the accepted answer but it's may need some time then i'm waiting and now it's marked as accepted !

Comment: I know this question is already answered but just wanted to share this basic but important lesson. One best way to find errors is to go to inspect or debug window. I think most browsers accept F12. Check console log for errors and also you can check network for any xhr/xmlhttp log.